# ASP Email sending error

Tags: asp.net

I have found this site very useful for all my previously faced problems, However i couldnt get help with the following.

I have developed a website which is able to send emails. On localhost this works absolutely fine. when i say localhost, i am able to recive the emails sent, but when i upload onto server i face this error when it starts the process of sending emails.

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IPADDRESS:PORT"

Tried ping on the adrress for the port and ping is working.

Here is the code

```
string strFrm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromAddress3"].ToString();

string[] receive = {"emailaddress1","emailaddress2","emailaddress3","emailaddress4"};

string subject = "New registration";

string body = "<html><head><title>Registered Candidates</title></head><body>bla bla bla</body></html>";

//I however have put reg exp validator on the form

if(txtEmail.Text.Contains("@") && txtEmail.Text.Contains("."))
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= receive.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(strFrm, receive[i], subject, body);
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        client.Send(msg);
     }

     Response.Redirect("Thankyou.html");
```

Web.config

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="from address">
    <network host="server" port="25"
userName="username" password="password"  />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Please help. I upload onto my server via precompilation of the site and upload the files.

Comment: Does the production server have SMTP enabled on localhost? Did you configure the SMTP settings in Web.config?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jakob.
Even in my localhost the program gets connected to the SMTP server and then sends a mail to the email addresses provided.
Yes. I have configured the settings in web config as well as as you can see above i have tried to over ride the settings while sending mail.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're overriding the SMTP address? And are you sure the server has SMTP enabled?

Comment: Sorry, I was just overriding the credentials. 
I however changed the the web.config. It looks something like this

<system.net>
<settings>
<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
</settings>
<mailSettings>
<SMTP from="from address">
<network host="server" port="25"
userName="username" password="pass"  />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>

and have removed 

NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Usr, Pwd);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = nc;

from the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.. :D

My hosting server was godaddy and my hosting plan supported only age old system.web.mail i.e CDOSYS concept.

Here is the code.

```
using System.Web.Mail;

private void SendEmail()
{
const string SERVER = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
MailMessage oMail = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
oMail.From = "emailaddress@domainname";
oMail.To = "emailaddress@domainname";
oMail.Subject = "Test email subject";
oMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html; // enumeration
oMail.Priority = MailPriority.High; // enumeration
oMail.Body = "Sent at: " + DateTime.Now;
SmtpMail.SmtpServer = SERVER;
SmtpMail.Send(oMail);
oMail = null; // free up resources
}
```

Thanks Jakob for participating actively! :)

Comment: Are you supplying blank username/pw now? Please edit your original question with your changes (this is an answer), and don't forget to change you servers' login/pw.

Comment: (you should delete this answer now)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're pointing to an SMTP service on your production server, it may not work on "localhost" as it does on your development machine. And pinging the server doesn't really tell you if it has SMTP enabled.

I generally prefer setting up SMTP for my sites in web.config:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="you@yourdomain.com">
      <network host="localhost" port="25" userName="user" password="pass" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

UPDATE:

If your code is working on your development machine, and it fails on the server with the same configuration, then there's probably something blocking. I would suggest trying to play around with a simple implementation that does nothing but test the servers SMTP configuration. You may want to try the `<smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">`, it's quite helpful when testing code that sends out emails. See the [SmtpDeliveryMethod Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpdeliverymethod.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Edited web.config. It looks something like this

<system.net>
<settings>
<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
</settings>
<mailSettings>
<SMTP from="from address">
<network host="server" port="25"
userName="username" password="pass"  />
</smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>

and have removed 

NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Usr, Pwd);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = nc;

from the program. but still i get the same.
When i said localhost, I hosted it on IIS and still this page connects to the same smtp server as in we.config to send the mail.

Comment: Update your question with your latest changes, including your web.config. :)

Comment: <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
This copies the email to a certain folder, which an external app can use to send the same email.
How is it useful in my solving my problem?

Comment: It's useful to confirm that your email-generating code is working, and you're *just* dealing with server configuration issues.

Comment: Jakob, am able to receive the email when run from my local system. but when loaded onto server i get that error.